# What happens to iCloud mail if storage payment fails

Tags: icloud, mail.app

I'm thinking of switching to iCloud Email and to buy more storage (currently 5gb) but im not sure if it's reliable to be charged for the storage on a monthly basis. Can someone tell me what happens if a payment fails for some reason, can I still receive messages for some time until I resolve the issue (even if unable to login to my mailbox) or the sender will receive a delivery error?

Answer (score 1):

Your data will remain but you won't be able to add more data until you reduce it back to below 5GB, i.e. If you have a 6GB backup, it will be unable to backup until you repay or you reduce your backup size below 6GB.

Comment: thanks for the answer. yeah, I know that if I exceed the storage limits, it's the default behavior to stop providing services for any email or storage provider, but I can't find information if even the first failed attempt to get money from the card meas limiting my storage to the free 5gb. that is equal to exceeding it if I have more than 5 gb stored. And in this case even email isn't different from the other data I think and you will not be able to add this "data" to the storage, right?

Comment: No idea. Sorry.